# Show Chinese character in ggplot2

Tags: r, utf-8, ggplot2

I just setup a Ubuntu 14.04 web server and change locale to zh_CN.UTF-8. However ggplot2 cannot show the Chinese characters in labels.

```
library(ggplot2)
x_lab <- enc2utf8('中国')
p <- ggplot(cars) + geom_point(aes(speed, dist)) +
xlab(x_lab)
png('a.png')
print(p)
dev.off()
```

The results look like this

[image]

Any idea to fix this problem?

PS: I have another web server with the same locale, but work fine to me.

This is my sessionInfo

```
> sessionInfo()
R version 3.3.1 (2016-06-21)
Platform: x86_64-pc-linux-gnu (64-bit)
Running under: Ubuntu 14.04.5 LTS

locale:
 [1] LC_CTYPE=zh_CN.UTF-8       LC_NUMERIC=C
 [3] LC_TIME=zh_CN.UTF-8        LC_COLLATE=zh_CN.UTF-8
 [5] LC_MONETARY=zh_CN.UTF-8    LC_MESSAGES=zh_CN.UTF-8
 [7] LC_PAPER=zh_CN.UTF-8       LC_NAME=C
 [9] LC_ADDRESS=C               LC_TELEPHONE=C
[11] LC_MEASUREMENT=zh_CN.UTF-8 LC_IDENTIFICATION=C

attached base packages:
[1] stats     graphics  grDevices utils     datasets  methods   base

other attached packages:
[1] ggplot2_2.1.0

loaded via a namespace (and not attached):
[1] colorspace_1.2-6 scales_0.4.0     plyr_1.8.4       gtable_0.2.0
[5] Rcpp_0.12.6      grid_3.3.1       munsell_0.4.3
```

Answer (score 0):

Figure out this problem. I need to install Chinese fonts in the new server, then roboot:

```
sudo apt-get install fonts-wqy-zenhei
sudo apt-get install fonts-arphic-bkai00mp fonts-arphic-bsmi00lp fonts-arphic-gbsn00lp fonts-arphic-gkai00mp fonts-arphic-ukai fonts-arphic-uming fonts-cns11643-kai fonts-cns11643-sung fonts-cwtex-fs fonts-cwtex-heib fonts-cwtex-kai fonts-cwtex-ming fonts-cwtex-yen
```

See this page: https://askubuntu.com/questions/490829/how-can-i-install-chinese-fonts-on-kubuntu-14-04